# Unable to consume SOAP webservice in Android

Tags: android, soap

I am working on code that will call a SOAP webservice under Android Java code, but in doing so I am not able to consume it, it's not returning any results.

I am giving two integers as input, and it will add the result in an output variable. For this I have called a webservice.

Also I am not sure based on this WSDL format what should I take as 
1.namespace,sooapaction,method

PLEASE FIND MY CODE IN BELOW URL

https://gist.github.com/deedood/9572246/revisions

Comment: Please include the [*relevant* parts of the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question rather than linking to the entire program and asking people to analyze the entire thing from the ground up and find problems. Also, please read this [advice on how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to follow the link at the bottom to Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule".